# Forwarding TCP connections (IP address to hostname)

Tags: port-forwarding, ip-address, hostname

I have got an online GPS tracker that connects to a TCP server and sends its current position to it every couple of seconds. The configuration of the tracker allows user to set the IP address of a server and its port.

My problem is that the TCP server application that receives data from the tracker works on a computer in my home network and I don't have a static IP address. This means that I have to reconfigure my tracker every 24 hours when my IP address changes.

I created an account on DynDNS.org website and configured DDNS section in my router, and it is accessible by a hostname now. This would solve my problem if only the thacker could accept hostnames instead of IP addresses. But it does not.

Is there a way to solve my problem easily? Maybe some kind of Internet service forwarding connections on a specified port to a given hostname? I don't know...

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not.
You need to have a box with a static IP - try a VPS. [Linode](http://linode.com/) have a nice plan for $20/mo with a public static IP.

The VPS can be configured to forward traffic to your machine, if you so wish, with something like `nc -vvLlp 1234 | nc yourbox 9876`, where 1234 is the port the GPS will connect to the VPS on, yourbox is the DynDNS hostname pointing at your box, and 9876 is the port the VPS should connect to your machine on.

Comment: It's a lot easier with ssh than with netcat.  `ssh -N -L 1234:localhost:9876 userid@yourbox`